# Parse custom [CODE] tags with no line breaks, format all other text with paragraphs

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have been playing around with this for a few hours now, and was curious as to the opinions of others on the best way to approach this.

I am making a CMS of sorts, and I want to be able to post code snippets.

I want to be able to surround said snippets with paragraphs of explanatory text.

What I want is for:

- The explanatory text to be formatted into paragraphs i.e str_replace `/n` for `</p><p>`.
- Whatever is contained within `[CODE][/CODE]` tags to not be formatted, and to have `htmlspecialchars()` applied to it so that any code is not executed.

I can achieve the latter point by using preg_replace_callback matching the text and applying htmlspecialchars in the callback function.

I suppose for the former point I could simply do the inverse expression, but that seems like the wrong way to do it.

Could anyone advise?

EDIT

Example code:
What I have so far..

```
function format_it($matches)
{
return "<pre class='prettyprint'>" . htmlspecialchars($matches['1']) . "</pre>";
}



$content=preg_replace_callback('#\[code\](.*)\[/code\]#isU', "format_it", $content);
```

Comment: Some example code would make your question clearer

Comment: I've added what Ive got so far to format the [CODE] tags as required. It is a case of how would achieve point one in the most optimal/efficient way..